# Prime number function

Tags: c++

I am taking a C++ class and I am frustrated with my code. I do not understand why my program thinks every number is a prime number. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num;

int isPrime(int num)
{
  for (int i=1; i<num ; i++) 
  // i is the divider, as long as it is less than the input number i++
  {
    if (i%num==0)
      return 0; //divider mod input number = 0 not prime
    else if (i=num)
      return 1; // divider = input number = prime.
  }
}

// return 1 for prime numbers and 0 for not prime
int main()
{
  cout << "Enter a positive integer";
  cin >> num;

  isPrime(num);

  if (isPrime(num)==1)
    {
      cout << " Yay its Prime";
    }
  else if ( isPrime(num)==0)
    {
      cout << " Nope not Prime";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i=num` is probably a mistake here. You need to develop an eye for `=` (assignment) vs. `==` (comparison).

Comment: C++ has `bool`. No reason to use `int` for Booleans.

Comment: I would also recommend changing your return type from 'int' to 'bool' on isPrime, and returning 'true' or 'false' instead of '0' or '1'. This will make the rest of the code clearer too. You could then do 'if (isPrime(num))'. And also just use else if there is only one more condition to check.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, You are both right I should have used == that makes sense; however, I made the change and I am still getting numbers like 10 and 100 as prime. Any other thoughts as to where I am screwing up?

Comment: Try changing `else if (i=num)` with `else if (i==num)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The below code is correct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num;

int isPrime(int num)
{
  for (int i=2; i<=num/2 ; i++) 
     if (num%i==0)
        return 0; //divider mod input number = 0 not prime

  return 1;
}

// return 1 for prime numbers and 0 for not prime
int main()
{
  cout << "Enter a positive integer";
  cin >> num;

  isPrime(num);

  if (isPrime(num)==1)
    {
      cout << " Yay its Prime";
    }
  else if ( isPrime(num)==0)
    {
      cout << " Nope not Prime";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use snippets for C++ code. They only work for Javascript, HTML, and CSS.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for your input. I am very surprised how fast you all responded to my request. I tried a little of everything that everyone suggested. The above code is working for me.

Again thank you all for your help

Comment: You should have provided details and descriptions along with the code, rather than providing only working code snippets....The question asker learns nothing and misunderstood SO as homework completing site..

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying Tejendra. I tried to modify my code with the suggestions below but I think I had an issue with the program I was using to write the code. We use Eclipse and for some reason after so many runs it gets stuck on an old save. So I created a new project and used the above code as it is what I was using before creating a new project. Again I want to thank everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You code can be improved. You do not need the `else if`, only `if`, because surely it will enter the `else branch` if it has not returned.

Also, replace `i=num` with `i == num`, since `==` is used for comparing and `=` for assigning the value.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `if (i%num==0)`. Put `if(num%i==0)`. Start loop from `2`!
2. Change `(i=num)` to `(i==num)`. However there is no sense in this line.

If you want a slightly more efficiency with very little effort you can have a loop

`for (int i=2; i * i <= num ; i++)`. The complexity will become *O(√num)* instead of *O(num)*. Resulting `isPrime` function will look like this:

```
int isPrime(int num)
{
    if(num <= 1) return 0; // <- 1 is not prime 
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) 
        if (num % i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Combined power of this answer and mine should fix it :D